Present perfect with time clauses
We don't use present perfect with exact time in the past.

I have done it in January or in 1999. Wrong

It doesn't only imply to dates but also to time clauses, am I right?

I have been to France twice when she was at home.

I think it's wrong.  We specify when so it should be "I visited France twice when…" without perfect.

It's not clear what (2) means. What's the connection between you going to France and her being at home? I have been to France twice when I was a child sounds OK to me, though in more formal usage went to might be better.

@KateBunting I have been (or went) to France in 1994 once, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, (all twice), 2023 (twice), and 2024 once (going again to Toulouse next week!). I might very well say that (or a shortened version!) if someone said 'Have you [ever] been to France?' The gap is explained by Catalunya and, latterly, Covid-19

"I have been to France in 1994" is not grammatical alone, but when included in a number of visits over multiple years which contribute to a sense of "over the course of my life"  then it is not an utterance about a discrete event at a particular time confined to the past, but brings in "present relevance" (over the course of my life).

Your statement about visiting her twice when she was at home:

I  have been to France twice when she was at home.

is not ungrammatical.  There is no time-phrase there that excludes the present.  "when she was at home" can be understood as a situation or condition. Maybe you visited several times when she herself was traveling and not at home.
When the utterance is about a discrete event confined to the past then the present perfect is ungrammatical.

Napoleon has been exiled to Elba in 1814. ungrammatical

When the utterance merely mentions some past years yet those past years are not meant to  confine an event to the past but to construct a pattern that amounts to a set of "life experiences", there is present relevance and those mentioned past years do not confine the events to the past and do not exclude the present:

I have been to France a number of times: in 1994, 2001, 2008, and 2015. grammatical

